MacTex Live Utility always asks for force removal of arara and arara.universal-darwin
How to prevent MacTex Live Utility from always asking for forced removal of arara and arara.universal-darwin?
This always happens and apparently nothing changes, I tried to search on google but found no leads.
my computer is equipped with an ARM M1 processor.
Nothing particular appears in the console of Tex Live Utility.

This seems to be very new behaviour. I'm seeing it too, but I don't think it happened with earlier updates, even of TL 2024.

That was a problem in/with MacTeX 2024.  Citing Herb Schulz in the OS X TeX mailing list:


Arara has an internal library that could not be `signed' by Apple.
Since our policy is to only include things that can be `signed' in
MacTeX.pkg arara had to be removed.
You can use TeX Live Utility (TLU) to re-install arara once you've
installed TeX Live 2024 with the MacTeX package. Open TLU and click on
the `packages' tab to list all available packages in TeX Live. Choose
the arara package (you may have to open the list of systems and choose
`universal-darwin') and then `Install Selected Packages' (or maybe
`Reinstall Selected Packages') in the Actions menu.


With other words: You will have to install arara once to satisfy TLU.  After that you can de-install it without TLU nagging again.

I've tried the answer you proposed, but it did not fix the problem, anyway, thanks for the time spent, it's not a blocking issue.

What do you mean that it didn't solve the problem? I reinstalled arara from the command-line: sudo tlmgr install arara. Are you saying that on subsequent updates it still gets removed?

I installed it not from the command-line but using Tex Live Utility, and then I reloaded the update list, It asked again for removal of arara, I validated, and after that I reloaded again and the message still appeared.

Thanks ! Installing from the command-line seemed to fix it.

Interesting.  I’ve had that problem myself but solved it using TLU as cited above.

Related question
